# error while creating environment in anaconda

Tags: python, compiler-errors, anaconda, package, open-source

I am trying to create an environment in anaconda but its showing error.
The code:

conda env create -f src/conda_env.yaml

the error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 565, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 552, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 337, in addsitepackages
    for sitedir in getsitepackages(prefixes):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 317, in getsitepackages
    libdirs = [sys.platlibdir]
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'platlibdir'
```

Comment: Could you please include a minimal YAML that triggers this?